# How to split pandas some of data frame rows that are not lists?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to change this data frame:

```py
40  4.5         95
41  1.76        95
112 0.17/0.43   >95/>95
```

to this using pandas:

```py
40  4.5         95
41  1.76        95
112 0.17        95
112 0.43        95
```

This is the pandas dataframe:

```
    a   b
19  560 80
40  4.5 95
41  1.76    95
112 0.17/0.43   >95/>95
154 7.2/1   >95/>95
... ... ...
2991    55  95
2992    33  95
3887    6.1 87.7
3893    3.9 70.3
3908    100 40
216 rows × 2 columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `explode`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split('/').explode(ignore_index=True))
```

Comment: The column `a` is my index column. How can I modify your code in this case? I tried removing the `set_index` from your code but that gives error.

Comment: @A.Razavi Edited my answer

Comment: I am getting error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: @A.Razavi Edited my answer

Comment: I am getting another error :`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @A.Razavi That must be a problem with your other code...

Comment: @A.Razavi Edited my answer

Comment: Still the same `ValueError`.

Comment: @A.Razavi Edited my answer

Comment: That gives me error `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'` I also tried this `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split('/').explode()), ignore_index=True)` but I get this error: `  df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split('/').explode()), ignore_index=True)
         ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`

Comment: @A.Razavi Edited mine

Comment: Cool! It is working now, is there a way to remove `>` and make all of the entries numeric?

Comment: I figured I can use these to remove `<` or `>` : `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('<',''))`